# How to let the input argument of a function be variable name in a created tibble inside function in R?

Tags: r, function, openxlsx

I am trying to create a custom function where I can create a "headline" column inside openxlsx's Writedata.

This is the function. Tab is the data, headline is quoted title, workbook is the wb, sheetname is the desired sheetname:

```
WriteToExcel <- function(tab, 
                         headline,
                         workbook=wb,
                         sheetName){

 
# title: I want this single row to have the input of the argument "headline"

So I create a tibble with 1 column with that name
headline <- tribble(
        ~colA,
         ) >%> rename(headline = colA)

openxlsx::writeData(workbook, sheetName, headline, startRow = nrow(readWorkbook("master.xlsx",
                                                   sheet = sheetName))+1, startCol = 1)

openxlsx::saveWorkbook(workbook, "master.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

}

WriteToExcel(tab=data, headline = "Task number three", sheetName = "Sheet 1")
```

However, this does not work. I have tried so many different things. How can I get the input to the function ("headline = "Task number three") to serve as the column name of a created dataframe / tibble inside the function, which I can then use as the data, containing the string argument as the only input?

Comment: your function doesn't use `tab`.. is that your intention? Also, there are no rows in the `headline` tibble that you create, even if we fix the naming issue.. What is your desired dim of `headline` tibble after it is created - 1 column  with 1 row,, or 1 column with 0 zeros, as you currently have designed?

Answer (score 0):

Within your function, perhaps create `x` like this:

```
x_data = tibble(!!headline:= headline)
```

Then `x_data` will have 1 column and 1 row, and both the column name and the value of that column in row 1 will be the same, like this:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  `Task Number Three`
  <chr>              
1 Task Number Three
```

Then pass `x_data` to the `x` parameter of `openxlsx::writeDate()`